# Input box not being posted

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im trying to grab a user input from one file, paste it on the same file, then send the input to another page. I'm not receiving any error but my code is not working either.

File 1
    from tkinter import *

```
win = Tk()
win.title("UPS")
win.geometry("300x300")
win.configure(background='white')

jjget = StringVar()

def sendover():
    grabbed_in = jjget.get()
    return grabbed_in

w11 = Label(win, text="Name")
w11.grid(row=1, column=0)

e22 = Entry(win, textvariable=jjget)
e22.grid(row=1, column=1)

mbuttonn = Button(win, text="Submit", command=sendover)
mbuttonn.grid(row=3, column=2)

print(sendover())
win.mainloop()
```

File 2

```
from file1 import *

name = sendover()

print(name)
```

Comment: In your code, what is `this`? Is it "File 1"?  Which file is the main file that is being run? Does "File 1" import "File 2", or is it "File 2" that is importing "File 1"? Please provide us more clear instructions. Also, please remove any import statements that are unrelated to the problem.

Comment: File 2 imports file 1. and okay will do

Comment: Are you trying to make "File 1" act like a dialog? Are you expecting "File 2" to call  `sendover` to open up the dialog and wait for a response?